# Are there more short and tricky codes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, shortcode

I found the following short and tricky codes on

Double bitwise NOT (~~) - James Padolsey
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/

Web Reflection: Two simple tricks in JavaScript ( olds, but always useful )
http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/06/two-simple-tricks-in-javascript-olds.html


double bitwise not

`Math.round(v)` === `~~v`

`Math.floor(v)` === `~~v` (if v > 0)

`isNaN(Number(v)) ? 0 : Number(v)` === `~~v`(if v is not float)


double not

`Boolean(v)` === `!!v`

(`!Boolean(v)` === `!v`)

bitwise shift

`Math.round(v / 2)` === `v >> 1`

`Math.round(v)` === `v >> 0`


single bitwise not

`a.indexOf(v) !== -1` === `~a.indexOf(v)`


Are there more short or tricky codes in javascript?

Comment: What are you after by using these tricks? I suggest you stay close to the Ecmascript standard. Some of the tricks are possible in Ecmascript.

Comment: `~~v` can *not* be equivalent to both `Math.round(v)` and `Math.floor(v)`, given that `round()` and `floor()` do *not* do the same thing. But even assuming it is equivalent to one or the other Math function using the `~~` shortcut just makes your code harder to read. Do you think somebody else reading that code will automatically understand that `Math.floor()` was the intended effect?

Comment: thanks your comments.
i just wanna make my codes tricky(but simple and cross-browser-compatible).
its fun to write code freely.
but this is difficult problem.
if you know what ~~, !! or ~-1 means, both readability and writabliity of the codes are better than the normal ways.
is it impossible that every javascript programer knows these tricks like every programer knows &&, !, ++, and etc?

Comment: @mozillanerd which ones are incomaptible with the Ecmascript standard?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer no, i didn't.

Comment: Useful link just in case someone find this will also like this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899495/is-there-a-good-js-shorthand-reference-out-there

Comment: `Math.round(2.6) //3` is NOT EQUAL to `~~2.6 //2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These "tricks" are not specific to Javascript.
A simple search on Google will return a number of pages offering tricks similar.

http://resnet.uoregon.edu/~gurney_j/jmpc/bitwise.html

http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/05/10/bitwise-gems-fast-integer-math/

http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/8/